# Rails Application for parsing content and filter only the reply part using gmail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I want to do is using scheduler task which checks for the incoming emails periodically and Parse the content and filter only the reply part of comments using gmail gem.I wrote scheduler task but I am not getting how to parse the content and filter only reply parts?

I have created rake task like this:

```
namespace :mail_comment do
  desc "TODO"
  task reply_to_comments: :environment do

  end
 end
```

I have used whenever gem for that and inside schedule.rb, I wrote

```
every 1.day do
  rake "mail_comment:reply_to_comments"
end
```

Could anyone please help me regarding this doubt? Thanks.

Comment: Did you write anything for the mail parsing part?

Comment: No, Actually I didn't get how to parse?